# TypeError: NoneType, can compare if equal, error when greater than

Tags: python, function, compare

I have written this code:

```
def reclen(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        if (10**i)%n==1:
            return(i)

for j in range(1,20):
    if reclen(j)==6:
        print(j)
```

And it will run, outputting the integers between 1-20 satisfying 1/n=has 6 recurring digits. If i change the clause in the second loop to:

```
for j in range(1,20):
    if reclen(j)>6:
        print(j)
```

I would expect to get the integers between 1-2 satisfying 1/n=has 6 or more recurring digits, but instead, i get an error, telling me there's a type error. I have tried plastering int() functions in all the outputs, but it seems I'm not allowed to compare the output as anything but exact equal to a value.

Comment: it works for me! the second clause output 17,19 -- I am using anaconda (python 2.7.9)

Comment: Note, `None` _can_ be compared to an int in python2.7 -- But the result is implementation dependent IIRC.

Comment: Strange that it will work in different builds... The problems stems from reclen() outputting "none" it seems? When defining the reclen() I can write:

    def reclen(n):
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            if (10**i)%n==1:
                return(i)
        return(0)

and the code will return 17,19 as is expected in this implementation.. **I cannot edit the reply to display the code propperly

Answer (score 1):

In the case where `n` is `1` in `reclen`, there will be nothing for your `for` loop to iterate over so it returns `None`.  e.g.:

```
>>> def reclen(n):
...     for i in range(1,n):
...         if (10**i)%n==1:
...             return(i)
... 
>>> print(reclen(1))
None
```

`None` is neither greater than or less than any integer (on python3.x where comparisons of different types are disallowed by default) which is why you get an error.

```
>>> None > 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```